# Figuring out which Azure region VM is in from within the VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We are looking to make decisions based on which azure region VM is in. I am hoping there is an environment variable being set or some other api to call from within the VM to retrieve the azure region.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Instance Metadata for that:

```
curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-12-01"
```

of powershell for windows

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{"Metadata"="true"} -URI http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01 -Method get
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service

the response will contain location among other things